# Reject the promise by itself,and then some console.log has no effect in firefox

Tags: javascript, promise

the code:

```
    var def = {}
    var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        def.reject = reject
    })

    p.catch(v => {
        console.log('reject')
        console.log(v)
    })

    def.reject(p)
    setTimeout(() =>console.log(p),0)
```

output normal in chrome,like this
[chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPA1D.png)

but just output 'reject' in firefox,like this
[firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8xvO.png)

why?
thanks first

Comment: Please show the exact output you get in both browsers so we can see the difference.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: @str  i see primise/A+ said 
If promise and x refer to the same object, reject promise with a TypeError as the reason.
so i tried to reject itself and this happened

Comment: This is an anti-pattern. Do not export the `resolve` and `reject` in the promise constructor executor. There are good reasons for it being designed the way it is. The resolution and rejection should be restricted to the executor function.